# grep awk or sed a CSV Row containing a certain part of a web address

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I am trying to clean up a Squid log file and I want to delete rows with a website containing "/0/" in the 11th column. An example:

```
Row1: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://blah.com/page/230/0/blah0.html
Row2: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://narph0.net/page/328/narph.htm
Row3: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://www.yahata.org/things/time/0/yahata.php
Row4: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://www.the.com/thethat/que303/yeah/main.php
```

Ignore the "*" in "http" because stackexchange thought those were real links.

Essentially I want to delete rows 1 & 3 but leave rows 2 & 4. I have tried about every `grep`, `awk` and `sed` command that I could find or think of. I can get `grep` to delete if there are elements in column1 but none of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want the lines not having `/0/` on the last column, you can do:

```
grep -v '[^[:blank:]]*/0/[^[:blank:]]*$' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% grep -v '[^[:blank:]]*/0/[^[:blank:]]*$' file
Row2: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://narph0.net/page/328/narph.htm
Row4: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://www.the.com/thethat/que303/yeah/main.php
```

On the other hand, if you precisely want to match the 11-th column, you can do:

```
grep -vE '^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){10}[^[:blank:]]*/0/[^[:blank:]]*$' file.txt
```

**Example: matching 5-th column**

```
% grep -vE '^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){4}[^[:blank:]]*/0/[^[:blank:]]*$' file
Row2: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://narph0.net/page/328/narph.htm
Row4: column1, column2, column3...column10, ht*p://www.the.com/thethat/que303/yeah/main.php
```

Comment: Both of those worked amazing. Thanks for the lesson!!